# What is meant by "free choice" in mathematics?

Tags: algorithms, definition, computer-science

The following quoted text was written before 1963, so the authors didn't have the benefit of decades of automated computing machines to inform their statements.

> The essential feature of an algorithm is that it requires no inspiration or inventiveness but only the ability to recognize sets of symbols and to combine them and break them up according to rule prescribed in advance;  in other words, in other words, *to carry out elementary procedures that can in principle be entrusted to a machine.*
>
> [$\dots$]
>
> In the above examples every stop is, in general, uniquely determined. But in other algorithms it may happen that each step depends upon a free choice among several (finitely many) possibilities. For example, consider the algorithm ($f$) which, when applied to two prescribed integers $a,b$ (in decimal notation), leaves open at each step a **free choice** between two possibilities: when two numbers (including $a$ and $b$) are already found, we may take (1) their sum or (2) their difference. This algorithm enables us to find all the numbers in the module $\left(a,b\right)$ generated by the two numbers $a$ and $b$.

Machines don't make "free choices".  I am aware that some manufacturers have from time-to-time attempted to produce "truly random" number generators.  But those ultimately appeal to some physical construct which is determined by the theories of physics to be "random".

I have no way of applying a meaningful mathematical interpretation to the term "free choice" in the above quoted text.  Is "free choice" a term that has a precise mathematical definition?

Comment: Randomness has, via [Kolmogorov's complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). And random sequences exist, it's an easy mathematical exercise to prove.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine ?

Comment: @rtybase That looks to me as though it could be applied to things which are deterministic but complicated—if something comes out the same every time, it's not randomly chosen.

Comment: In the quote, it sounds as if the machine deterministically follows the instructions, but some instructions can be to make a non-deterministic step like "choose $A$ if the next radioactive decay is detected on the left, and $B$ if it's detected on the right". But that makes it randomly determined, not freely chosen.

Comment: So the "free choice" is external to the algorithm, which remains deterministic.

Comment: @timtfj Perhaps we could entrust the execution of the algorithm to a cat in a box.

Comment: I don't believe there is any mathematically rigorous definition of "free choice" but it's typical to use colloquial language when discussing randomness unless technical details are required. This should not be confused with the philosophical notion of free will which implies agency in the choice rather that given a set of acceptable outputs some specific output is chosen by some means.

Comment: You might like to look at Brouwer's "choice sequences": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_sequence

Comment: @StevenHatton I wouldn't entrust *anything* to a cat even if I was in a thought experiment.

Comment: Maybe free choice means simply "Let $x\in \{a, b\} $".

Comment: @timtfj that definition of randomness is related to a sequence that was generated, somehow. It is random if it can't be "compressed", i.e. there is no pattern in it. Generally, Kolmogorov complexity is uncomputable, for the same reasons halting problem is undecidable over Turing machines, which in turns is related to Gödel's incompleteness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the quote is only talking about [non-deterministic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine).

In this particular case, we can formally define "leaves open a free choice" by saying:

> A particular output is *possible* from a given input if there is at least one sequence of choices that leads the algorithm to that output from that input.

If there is more than one option at some stage of the algorithm, then more than one output may be possible from a given input.

The term "free" only means that every possible choice at each step is considered when we ask about whether a particular output is possible; the "choices" are not constrained in any way.

Note that we do not define what "free choice" means - we define what it means for an algorithm to lead from an input to an output if there are possible choices along the way. This is similar to the way that "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$" is defined in calculus without actually defining what it means to "approach zero".

As an example taken from Wikimedia Commons [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NFAexample.svg), the following flowchart shows a process that begins with a "free choice" of going from $S_0$ to $S_1$ or $S_2$. This flowchart accepts the regular language  $(1^*(01^*01^*)^*) \cup (0^*(10^*10^*)^*) \cup \epsilon$; the top half accepts the first option, while the bottom half accepts the second.

When we talk about "running" the algorithm on a specific input, we formally mean to consider every path through the flowchart that agrees with the input, and we say that the input is accepted if there is at least one path that leads to an accepting state. By considering every path, we consider every possible sequence of choices; this can be colloquially defined as imagining that someone "makes a free choice" whenever a choice is possible.

[image: NDFA]

Comment: In the particular example given, it seems that a completely deterministic algorithm could be used by simply following each "branch" to one deeper level and recording the outcomes.  But that would apparently require a broadening of the definition of "algorithm", or at a minimum, significantly changing the definition of the given algorithm. In order for me to accept your answer, I would like to see a complete statement of your proposed definition.

Comment: The free choice is in the definition of the algorithm. In the flowchart, we can go from $S_0$ to $S_1$ **or** to $S_2$. That "or" is the free choice - the algorithm gives no instructions about which one to choose, and we are "free" to choose either one.

Comment: It's probably immaterial, but I was not clear in what I meant by the "given example".  I was referring to the example in my original question.  In the case of, for example, binomial distribution are we to understand "free choice" as meaning there are two branches at every node of the expansion tree?  By the "expansion tree" I mean http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_06.html#Ch6-F4

Comment: Just to remark that the link given in the answer leads to "non-deterministic Turing Machine". The link for "non-deterministic algorithm" is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

The rationale behind free (or arbitrary) choices, is that the algorithm will remain correct whatever the choice(s). Leaving the choice open may create opportunities for optimizations. This option is left to the implementor who will usually define a deterministic choice rule.

Machines making truly random choices are rare, and not so useful (except maybe in high-end cryptographic applications).